# Move E-Mails to subfolder of inbox using sieve

Tags: email, inbox, dovecot

Do I need any option, to move matching emails to a subfolder of the inbox?

My /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf:

```
    namespace inbox {
      inbox = yes
    }
```

And the /srv/vmail/spam-global.sieve:

```
    if address "From" "monitoring@example.com" {
            fileinto "INBOX.Monitoring";
    }
```

This configuration is currently creating a new main folder "INBOX.Monitoring" instead of an INBOX subfolder "Monitoring".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `/` as parent-child separator: `"INBOX/Monitoring"`

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Have you tried testing using `sieve-test` program?

Comment: "Invalid mailbox name: Name must not have '/' characters" (Dovecot 2.3.4.1)